# SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' returns metadata table in sqlite in Android Pie

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using a Google Play Android API 28 (Android PIE) emulator. My code is

```
Cursor cursor_names = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'", null);
Log.e("Cursor Count",cursor_names.getCount()+"");
cursor_names.moveToFirst();
while (!cursor_names.isAfterLast()) {
      String name=cursor_names.getString(cursor_names.getColumnIndex("tbl_name"));
      Log.e("Table Name",name);
      cursor_names.moveToNext();
 }
```

The Logcat is

```
E/Cursor Count: 1
E/Table Name: android_metadata
```

Where is on previous android versions I get the tables list and each and every query executes. What is the issue with android 9 ?

Comment: What's the database you're running this on? It looks like the default setup when creating a new empty database on a device.

Comment: SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

Comment: So the sqliteopenhelper is not creating any tables there.

Comment: Actually this piece of code works perfectly on any API lower than 28. So SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); works in android API 27. But I have no idea why it fails to work in API 28

Comment: Anyway the issue is in your sqliteopenhelper implementation.

Comment: Ok I will check this now. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with

```
if (cursor_names.moveToFirst()) {
    while ( !cursor_names.isAfterLast() ) {
        String name=cursor_names.getString(cursor_names.getColumnIndex("tbl_name"));
        cursor_names.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

Alternate

```
 // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            // Your work
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
```

Comment: you are right but the output is still the same. Any thoughts on why I am getting the metadata instead of list of tables ?

Comment: @JalalKhan Debug please.

Comment: It works on all other Android devices whose API is lower than 28. It makes me pointless.